# Find the interval of $a$ that makes $x^2e^{ax}-1\gt \ln x$ true.

Tags: calculus, inequality

$$x^2e^{ax}-1\gt \ln x$$

Then $e^{ax}\gt \frac{\ln x+1}{x^2}$

Let $f(x)=\frac{\ln x+1}{x^2}$, then $f'(x)=\frac{-2\ln x-1}{x^3}$, and $f''(x)=\frac{6\ln x+1}{x^4}$

$-2\ln x-1=0\Rightarrow x=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

$f''(e^{-\frac{1}{2}})=-2e^2 \lt0$

Therefore it is the maximum point for $f(x)$ when $x=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Then $e^{ae^{\frac{1}{2}}}\gt f(e^{-\frac{1}{2}})=\frac{e}{2}$

Therefore $ae^{-\frac{1}{2}}\gt1-\ln2 \Rightarrow a\gt\sqrt e(1-\ln2)$

But the answer is $a\gt\frac{e}{3}$

How do they get $a\gt \frac{e}{3}$?

Comment: Where did you get the awnser $\frac{e}{3}$? Graphing on desmos, it seems your awnser should be correct..

Comment: It is the question of the practice booklet. I have the answer but do not know how do they get that.

Comment: Or maybe it can be solved in other ways?

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to do that? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of solution is wrong. If you want
$$e^{ax}>{1+\log x\over x^2}\qquad\forall\>x>0\tag{1}$$
it is not sufficient to find the maximal point $\xi$ of the RHS and then to make sure that the inequality is true at this point $\xi$. In fact the value $a=\sqrt{e}(1-\log2)=0.505915$ you have found is too small, and the graphs of the LHS and RHS intersect for this value of $a$.

If we want $(1)$ then we can as well ask for
$$a>{\log(1+\log x)-2\log x\over x}=:g(x)\qquad\forall\>x>0\ .$$
When we graph $g$ we obtain the following picture:

[image]

There is a unique maximum at $\xi:=0.56849$ (can not be computed elementarily) with $$a_*:=g(\xi)=0.523596\ .$$
If $a>a_*$ then the desired inequality holds for all $x>0$. Your $a=0.505915$ is transcended by $g$ in an $x$-interval of positive length. The value $a':={1\over3}e>0.9$ is sufficiently large, but obviously too large.

Comment: So actually the answer booklet is wrong? I use my graphing calculator to do it too... Thanks with that.